# I'm trying to read a file into a vector and keep getting this error

Tags: c++, file, vector

I keep getting this error:

```
 error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::ifstream’
 {aka ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>’} and ‘std::vector<symbol>’)
   26 |             myFile >> temp;
      |             ~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~
```

```
int readAlphabetFromFile(string filename, vector<symbol> alphabet) {
    ifstream myFile;
    myFile.open(filename);
    if (myFile.is_open()) {
        while (!myFile.eof()) {
            vector<symbol> temp;
            myFile >> temp;
            alphabet.push_back(temp);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't read dirctly into a vector.  I think you want to read into `symbol temp;`  (Although that depends on the definition of symbol.

Comment: @AShelly symbol is a structure

Comment: the while-not-eof is wrong   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons

Comment: Unless you offered an overload for your structure, the >> operator can't read into a structure. Same for a vector of your structure. Your compiler must be trying you that none of this is defined!

Comment: You must think that C++ is black magic and could intelligently do whatever you ask it to do, but no, it doesn't know how to do `>>` for your custom-defined `symbol`, in fact, it doesn't know to do anything unless you specifically teach it how to do so. [C++ ifstream and ofstream overloading operator reading from file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38232496/13253010)

Comment: You need to change `vector<symbol> temp;` to `symbol temp;` and then implement `operator>>` for `symbol`. Also, `alphabet` needs to be passed in by reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
myFile >> temp;
```

In C++ an overloaded `>>` operator is defined for just a few elementary types and classes; namely it's defined for all numerical and floating point types, `std::string`, and a few other simple things.

This `temp` is a `std::vector` of some unknown type named `symbol`.

There is no defined overload of the `>>` operator for a vector of anything. Additionally if you defined a class named `symbol` there's not going to be a `>>` overload of that, either.

```
while (!myFile.eof()) {
```

Another problem with the shown code is that [this is always a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons).

There are very few things in C++ that work by default. If your goal is to read a vector of these `symbol`s, whatever they are, you will need to write all the logic and all the code to do that, step by step, all by yourself. C++ will not do it for you. You will also need to use appropriate logic for checking for an end of file condition, as explained in the preceding link.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that the compiler can't find an `operator>>` for reading a `std::vector` from a `std::ifstream`, which is true.

However, `alphabet` is a `vector` of `symbols`, so you need to push `symbol` objects into it, but you are trying to push another `vector` instead. You need to change `vector<symbol> temp;` to just `symbol temp;` and then implement `operator>>` for `symbol`.

Also, `alphabet` needs to be passed in to your function by reference or pointer, but you are passing it in by value, so you are acting on a *copy* of the caller's `vector`, not the original.

Also, `while (!myFile.eof())` is a logic error that needs to be fixed: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/)

Try this instead:

```
istream& operator>>(istream &in, symbol &sym) {
    // read from 'in' into 'sym' as needed...
    return in;
}

int readAlphabetFromFile(string filename, vector<symbol> &alphabet) {
    ifstream myFile(filename);
    if (myFile.is_open()) {
        symbol temp;
        while (myfile >> temp) {
            alphabet.push_back(temp);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```